# Sorting an Struct Array in C without Pointers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, struct

i am a Newbie in C and yet not so familiar with Pointers in C ...

I am trying to implement a function which sorts an Struct Array like this:

```
typedef struct Album {
    char titel[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    char interpret[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    unsigned short releaseYear;
    enum conditionEnum condition; //1 = sehr gut, 2 = gut, 3 = mittel, 4 = schlecht, 5 = sehr schlecht
};
```

I wrote this sort-function:

```
void bubblesort(struct Album yourArray[], int arraysize)
{
    struct Album tmp;
    for (int i = arraysize; i > 1; i--)     //loop that makes the bubblesort smaller --> defines endcriteria
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++)     //loop for the not sorted data
        {
            if (yourArray->releaseYear[j] > yourArray->releaseYear[j + 1]) //comparing first value with the second value
            {
                tmp = yourArray[j];            //the biggest value is stored in a tmp value
                yourArray[j] = yourArray[j + 1]; //swapping process (7 > 5) --> the smaller value moves forward (j - Stelle) --> 7 goes to 5
                yourArray[j + 1] = tmp;        //swapping process (7 > 5) --> the biggest value moves backwards (j + 1 - Stelle) --> 5 goes to 7
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my IDE says

> "expression must have pointer to object type"

Could someone please help me and explain me how to deal with this? In my Code i initialize the Array as: `struct Album Alben[5];`

Thanks Alex

Comment: `yourArray->releaseYear[j]`  should be `yourArray[j].releaseYear`

Comment: god thanks ... can you explain what i did wrong?

Comment: You need to index the array, while each indexed member is of type `struct Album` type, which is not a pointer, so to access it's members you use `.` operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of structs. You can fetch one of the items in the array, and then that item is a struct.

You should use `yourArray[j].releaseYear` which means:

1. Access the `j`th item in `yourArray` - which is a struct.
2. Access the `releaseYear` field in that struct.

What you had is `yourArray->releaseYear[j]` which means:

1. Access the item pointed to by `yourArray` - which is a struct. (For reasons you will find out about later, this is the same as `yourArray[0]`).
2. Access the `releaseYear` field in that struct.
3. Access the `j`th item in the `releaseYear` field, but this is not valid because `releaseYear` isn't an array.

Comment: Ahh okay makes sense just the Struct is an Array .. Thank you for that explanation!